# Sort by boolean value inside collect

Tags: groovy

I have list of map

```
students.collect {
                [
                    id: it.id,
                    cell: [it.id, checkIfTrue(it.id, sessionsByUser)]
                ]

            }
```

This gives o/p

```
[[id:7, cell:[7, false]], 
 [id:8, cell:[8, true]], 
 [id:9, cell:[9, false]]
```

based on some condition I need to sort this list using boolean value. So for true it should be

```
[[id:8, cell:[8, true]],
 [id:7, cell:[7, false]], 
 [id:9, cell:[9, false]]
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What You need is a `sort` method, not `collect`:

```
def m = [
    [id:1,cell:[1,false]],
    [id:2,cell:[2,true]],
    [id:3,cell:[3,false]],
]

assert [
[id:2,cell:[2,true]],
[id:1,cell:[1,false]],
[id:3,cell:[3,false]],
] == m.sort {!it.cell[1]}
```

Comment: but cell has lot of values like a list cell:[1,true,'abc',2] instead of 'cell:true'. So how only 'true' can be recognized?

Comment: If it has fixed order then by index. If not it can't.

Comment: index will be fixed. Like it would be on 2nd position inside the list cell:[1,true]    cell:[2,false] like this.

Comment: Edited the answer, now should be ok.

Answer (score 3):

You can't sort in collect, but you can sort after collect:

```
  students.collect {
    [
      id: it.id,
      cell: [it.id, checkIfTrue(it.id, sessionsByUser)]
    ]

  }.sort {
    it.cell[1]
  }
```